# My PC freezes and makes loud noise on speakers

Tags: hard-drive, freeze

I have this issue: my PC is randomly freezing and making loud noise on speakers sometimes.

Incidentally, my Hard Drive seems to be with problems. Everytime I log in to windows, I get a warning: Windows detected a problem in the Hard Drive. My system boots on an SSD, not a hard drive though.

Are these problems connected? How can I solve them?

Comment: The first thing to do when a computer tells you that it has detected a problem on a hard drive is **backup all the data you need to keep**. Ignore that it refers to a hard drive: it is not differentiating between an SSD and an HDD. Let us know when you've done the backup and then we can get on with finding out what the problem is.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for responding.

I just bought a new computer (not entirely. I have bought: processor, video card, motherboard etc. Everything EXCEPT a harddrive. And I've bought a SSD). So, I have no data to backup actually. The only thing that is "old" is the harddrives.

Comment: What sort of noise? 60 Hz buzz indicates power supply issue or ground loop (perhaps through external speaker power supply), for example.

Comment: It is not the same pitch always, I think. I don't know how to describe it. It seems like interference.

Comment: have you done a **chkdsk /r c: **

Comment: I assume that this is a computer which you have put together yourself. It sounds like you may have a poor or intermittent electrical connection somewhere. I suggest that you unplug the PC from the mains electrical supply, wait a couple of minutes, and then disconnect and reconnect *all* the connectors in the PC (no need to re-install the CPU, though). You only need to do them one at a time. Also, it will give you a chance to make sure that none of the cables are pinched anywhere and perhaps route them more tidily.